# HTTP REFERER isn't set

Tags: php

i have some error, why HTTP_REFERER isn't set, this is my code,

this is in index.php

```
 if(!isset($_GET['p'])){
        include '_include/start.php';                       
    }else{
        switch ($_GET['p']) {
        case 'admin':       include '_admin/admin.php';  break;
        case 'home':    include '_include/home.php'; break;

        }//end case

   }//end if
```

first i'm in index.php that `$_GET[p]` isn't set so it will be include start.php then i go to home case, then i put link to back to address before, but i got error that HTTP REFERER isn't set, anyone can help me?

Comment: So where are you actually referencing HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: It is also up to the browser to pass this on. The browser/proxy is free not to do so - therefore do not rely on it

Answer (score 0):

It is because no web page is referring to that page. You are just putting in the URL of the page and accessing it. To make the previous page as a referrer, you need to add a link on the previous page and then use it to open the next page.